# Converting 2D point cloud to polygon using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point

There was similar questions, but not exactly what I need, so I am asking here.

Is there a way to create polygons from these points in the picture?

[image]

The result I want to achieve in this picture >>

[image]

The points in the picture is GPS points from transport working in the field. From those points I want to have polygon geometries for future calculations of area and boundaries.

Zoomed out version of my GPS points in 1:1,500,000

[image]

Comment: How should the polygon look like? Do you want a convex or concave hull around the points? For a convex hull there is a tool in QGIS (vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Convex Hull(s)). Or the Concave Hull plugin in the official QGIS repositories.

Comment: A view words about your data and what do you want to achieve with that polygons would be helpful as well.

Comment: @Stefan - I edited my question. Hope it is clear! :)

Comment: Please provide link(s) to any similar question(s) so that potential answerers do not need to look for them before answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcMap 10.2.2 you can approximately achieve this by running the **Minimum Bounding Geometry** tool, under Data Management Tools toolbox. Particularly, you have to choose *convex_hull* under Geometry Type. At the end, you could do some corrections of the polygon manually.

Comment: I tried, it only creates minimum bounding polygon from all the points in the layer. It could work if I had my GPS points in different layers by chunks of time.

Comment: I see. I suppose you don't have any attribute that refers to time...

Comment: Not likely, no..

Comment: @risk_ltu There's nothing in the question to indicate you dont want all point to be considered at once - perhaps you need to edit

Answer (score 0):

The best way is convert point to raster (indicate cell size to avoid gaps) then create polygon from raster.

Comment: Could you please go into detail on how to perform that using ArcMap?

Answer (score 0):

The operation you want to apply is known in map generalisation as *amalgamation*.

A fast way to achieve it automatically (using ArcMap) is the following:

- Compute a **buffer** of your input geometries with a distance *d*. The output is a set of polygons (for your case, these should be circular polygons). In ArcMap, use [that](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm).
- Compute the **union** of these polygons (orange line on the image below). In ArcMap, use [that](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm).
- Compute a **buffer** of the union with... (here is the trick) **a negative distance *-d***. You would obtain something like the purple line below. You might use a slightly different value, such as *-0.01*d* to ensure the result remains polygonal.

How to choose the *d* parameter? This should be the threshold distance you consider as relevant to see two points amalgamated in the same polygon. You should maybe test several values and see the result.

[image]